# Solr.log file was not updating with latest information

Tags: solr

Since last 4 months solr.log file was not updating/growing with the latest solr logs information. we have properly configured the log4j.properties file and log4j.xml files. whenever we are restarting the solr service the only "solr-8983-console.log" updated with solr restart time stamp. we have verified the solr.log file location on server level with find command but it's showing only what we configured on .properties file location.

Need your help on how solr admin console showing latest logs information and From where it is pulling the latest logs from server.

Solr version :7.5
Server type: linux

Comment: Solr switched to log4j2 and the configuration format is different. Did you upgrade your Solr version at that time?